# Can't find next highest value in array

Tags: javascript

```
// winningCombinationsState is an array of 8 integers ranging from 0 to 3.
// Game.winningCombinations is an array of 8 arrays containing 3 integers each ranging from 0 to 8.
// Game.state is an array of 9 strings. It keeps the record of the 2 player's position on the board. 

function bestMove () {
    let index; 
    while (index == undefined) {
        // Find index of first Math.max(...array) 
        let max = winningCombinationsState.indexOf(Math.max(...winningCombinationsState));
        // Check for the first empty slot within Game.state at indexes Game.winningCombinations[max]
        for (let slot in Game.winningCombinations[max]) {
            if (Game.state[slot] == "") {
                index = slot;
                break;
            }  
        }
        // Remove the best array if no empty slot were found.
        if (index == undefined) {
            delete winningCombinationsState[max];
        }
        // While Game.state[slot] isn't an empty string then keep searching. 
    }
    return index;
}
```

It works well but sometimes it gets stuck.

When index's left `undefined` I have this error `Game.winningCombinations[max] is not iterable`

Tried using a `for ... in` which lift the error message but it still get stuck and sometimes runs into an infinite loop ...

`console.log(typeof Game.winningCombinations[max])` tells me it's an object but it's defined as an array of arrays within an object.

An example of what I am trying to do.

```
// State of the board 
Game.State = [“X”,””,”O”,””]

// Winning combinations of Game.State[index]
Game.winningCombinations = [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]

// Map Game.state to Game.winningCombinations
// Such as “X” -> 1, “O” -> -1, else 0
// Make abs(sum)
WinningCombinationsState = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

// Find index of max. See code block above. 
max = indexof(Math.max(…)) // Returns 0
```

In this example `index = 1` because `Game.state[ Game.winningCombination[max][1] ]` is an empty string

Trying to find the next best move based on the `max` but if no empty `slot` is available then find the next best move.

Comment: What are you trying to do

Comment: @Spectric I am trying to get the max from [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
Then check if myArray[max] contains an empty string within it. Knowing that myArray[max] is an array containing 3 items.

Comment: What output you want? You want to show just one value like **3** ?

Comment: @Newbee That's it. I want to return an integer that ranges btw 0 and 8. Some code is missing here but I didn't provide it for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

First error: the array winninCombinationsState has 9 object; if the index of the first max integer is 8, then the next code won't work, because it has only 8 array making its max index to be 7 (counting from 0)

```
let max = winningCombinationsState.indexOf(Math.max(...winningCombinationsState))
```

Actualy, the Game.winningCombinations[max] should be an Array, then

```
Game.state[slot] === ""
```

is same than

```
Game.state[[0, 3, 2]] === ""
```

while it is expecting an integer as index;

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedbacks !

You're right winningCombinationsState has actually 8 items. It's a mistake from me.

As for `Game.state[slot]`, `slot` isn't an array but an integer. Actually, this one works correctly as the loop *for each slot of this array[index]* provides an integer. 

I messed up with my comments ...

Answer (score 0):

You have little confused at using `delete winningCombinationsState[max]`, I think.

You can test at google console like this.

```
a = [1,2,3,4];
Math.max(...a);   /* result: 4 */
a.indexOf(Math.max(...a));    /* result: 3 */

delete a[2];   /* result: true */
a;   /* result: [1,2, undefined, 4] */
Math.max(...a);   /* result: NaN */
```

So, you should remade the array named `winningCombinationsState` by this code:

```
winningCombinationsState = winningCombinationsState.filter(i => i != undefined)
```

Then use this array variable!
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Got `delete` completely wrong and I wasn't aware about the side effect with Math.max()

Thanks for pointing out the problem and providing a solution !

Instead of `delete` we can `splice(max, 1)`

Comment: Good, plz don't forget the max of ```splice(max,1)``` means, the index of max number not the value of it.

Comment: That’s true ! Actually the `max` value is a reference to the index containing the highest value. Which is then used to check if an empty string or `slot` belongs here. If there’s no empty string then remove this index from the array and find the next best `max` while `index` is left undefined. 

However I still run into the same issue. `index` is left undefined while there are empty slots available on the board.